# Неудачная попытка деплоя бота на хероку

Tags: python, telebot, heroku, pywin32

Я пытался задеплоить бота на хероку, через пайчарм. Я установил requirements.txt и Procfile , но после команды `git push heroku master`

Ошибка:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==304 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==304
```

Requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
crypto==1.4.1
idna==3.3
Naked==0.1.31
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==304
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
shellescape==3.8.1
telebot==0.0.4
urllib3==1.26.11
```

Comment: Ну нету там видимо pywin32 версии 304

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67852945/9441900 думаю вам подойдет

Comment: @oleksandrigo да, я запустил бота, все прошло удачно, но он не отвечает, ошибок логи не выдают. Я написал в Procfile bot: python news-bot-code , но если вместо bot в начале напишу web, то работает 60 секунд, после чего не находит порта и отключается.